# Is there a program that can make your mouse pointer jump to the next monitor?

Tags: mouse, multiple-monitors

I use multiple monitors (with Synergy), and I'd like to make the mouse pointer jump over to the next monitor without having to move it. Yes, I am that lazy. Does a program that does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either of these in your config file:

**keystroke(alt+left) = switchInDirection(left)**
Switches to the screen to left when the left arrow key is pressed in combination with the Alt key.

**keystroke(shift+control+alt+super) = switchToScreen(moe)**
Switches to screen moe when all of the Shift, Control, Alt, and Super modifier keys are pressed together.

Via http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html